# E/Volley: [251] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http:/example/some/api02/registerUser.php

Tags: java, php, android, authentication, backend

I keep getting this error and I just cannot figure out why. Im trying to send a username, a password and an email to a server.
The URL is 100% correct, I checked it like 100 times.
But look at the code youself:
The Client code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText et_username, et_password, et_email;
private Button btn_createAccount;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_username = findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    et_password = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    et_email = findViewById(R.id.et_email);

    btn_createAccount = findViewById(R.id.btn_createAccount);
    btn_createAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createUserAccount();
        }
    });

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
}

private void createUserAccount() {
    final String username = et_username.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = et_password.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = et_email.getText().toString().trim();

    progressDialog.setMessage("Creating your Account...");
    progressDialog.show();
    
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_REGISTER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("email", email);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

The serverside code:

```
<?php

require_once "../config02/db.php";

$response = array();

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

$username_err = $password_err = $email_err = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
        $username_err = "Username is empty";
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $username_err;
    } else {
        $sql = $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username";
        
        if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
            } else {
                $username_err = "Oops! Somethinh went wrong";
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = $username_err;
            }

            unset($stmt);
        }
    }

    if (empty(trim($_POST["password"]))) {
        $password_err = "Password is empty";
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $username_err;
    } else {
        $sql = $sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = :password";
        
        if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bindParam(":password", $param_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $param_password = trim($_POST["password"]);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
            } else {
                $password_err = "Oops! Somethinh went wrong";
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = $username_err;
            }

            unset($stmt);
        }
    }

    if (empty(trim($_POST["email"]))) {
        $email_err = "Email is empty";
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $username_err;
    } else {
        $sql = $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email";
        
        if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $param_email = trim($_POST["email"]);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
            } else {
                $email_err = "Oops! Somethinh went wrong";
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = $email_err;
            }

            unset($stmt);
        }
    }

    if (empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($email_err)) {
        $sql =  "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, :username, :password, :email);";

        if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":password", $param_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $param_email = $email;

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['message'] = "Registered User successfully really";
            } else {
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = "Registered User failed";
            }

            unset($stmt);
        }
    }

    unset($pdo);
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

If you need more details, just ask. Also I am using the volley networking library.

Comment: Typo: `$POST` ? (may not be the root cause, just caught my eye)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't worked. Keep throwing the same error. But thank you for trying

Comment: Ok, any clues in the error log?

Comment: No, it just prints out the error in the title. So I think this has to be an error on the serverside code.